# Is SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher is compatible with connecting to SQL data warehouse?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-mobile

Is it possible to for SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher to connect with SQL data warehouse?

Comment: Probably. Why don't you try and see.

Comment: I already tried and I was not able to connect. And I am not sure whether it is even compatible with SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher.

Comment: You need to edit your question and describe in what way you were "unable to connect". Did you get an error or did you just not know how to do it? Right now I can't think of any reason that it would not function. If you describe your specific issue then I can probably make some suggestions but right now there is no clue what your actual issue is.

Comment: In the first instance.... can you actually connect to SQL Data Warehouse with any other tool such as SQL Server Management Studio? Can you run the required SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio?